# 'ANY_NODE_APP' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file on windows 10

Tags: visual-studio-code, tslint

I use windows 10 OS . I already try :

```
npm i -g tslint
```

also local install.

I use visual code terminal (power shell , git bash and cmd ) no help in any variant.

Where is the execution file for tslint ? I will put path intro the `PATH` env var.

Comment: @rhavelka, given that [the homepage for tslint](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/) gives a quick start where they install globally, it's safe to say it does work globally.

Comment: Not work at all. It was work before some time...

Comment: Only way to work fine is : `node PATH/node_modules/someModule.js `  It is problem just tslint i cant start any other also. Strange but it is true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is probably caused by the version conflict between global and project's TsLint. You can see your version by: `tslint -v`

Then you can reinstall Tslint globally to latest version by:
`npm install tslint typescript -g`

Then use following command in your project directory to even up versions. 
`npm install tslint typescript --save-dev`

And also you can search in your json files if there is a specification about Tslint version.

Comment: I have no problem with any missing package or bad install. I already have all global also local ... When i use `node PATH/node_modules/someModule.js someApp.js` everything works fine...